# Why $p(x-y) \geq p(y)-p(x)$,implies $p(x-y) \geq |p(y)-p(x) |$ for the seminorm $p$

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

In this lecture[Fucntional Analisys II](https://irma.math.unistra.fr/%7Esabri/Lectures_FA.pdf) at page 2 the author has

> Definition 1.1. Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$
> or $\mathbb{C}$. A function $p: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called a
> seminorm if
>
> (i) $p(x+y) \leq p(x)+p(y)$ for $x, y \in X$ (sub-additivity),
>
> (ii) $p(\lambda x)=|\lambda| \cdot p(x)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$
> and $x \in X$ (positive homogeneity).
>
> Lemma 1.2. Let $p$ be a seminorm on a vector space $X$. Then
>
> (a) $p(0)=0$,
>
> (b) $p(x) \geq 0$,
>
> (c) $|p(x)-p(y)| \leq p(x-y)$,
>
> Proof. By homogeneity, $p(0)=p(0 \cdot x)=0 \cdot p(x)=0$, which is
> (a). By sub-additivity, $p(x) \leq p(x-y)+p(y)$, so $p(x-y) \geq p(x)-p(y)$. Substituting $x$ for $y$ we get $p(x-y)=|-1| \cdot p(y-x)
>  \geq p(y)-p(x)$, so (c) follows. In particular, $p(x) \geq|p(x)-p(0)|
>  \geq 0$, which is (b).

My question is why   $p(x-y)
 \geq p(y)-p(x)$,implies $p(x-y)
 \geq |p(y)-p(x) |$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By (ii) $P(-x)=p(x)$. So $p(x-y)
 \geq p(y)-p(x)$ gives $p(x-y)=p(y-x)
 \geq p(x)-p(y) =-(p(y)-p(x))$. combining these two inequalities we get $p(x-y)
 \geq |p(y)-p(x)|$.

($t \geq s$ and $t \geq -s$ imply $t \geq |s|$ since $|s|$ is either $s$ or $-s$).